# Access swift class in objective c parent class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have created a hybrid App which has both Objective-c and Swift classes.

I have a Main View Controller (parent) from which all other View Controllers are inherited (both written in Objective-c and Swift).

Now the issue I am facing is that I want to access a swift class inside my MainViewController but when I add `#import "MyProjectName-Swift.h"` in `MainViewController.h`, I got tons of errors.

The reason for that is because my swift view controllers are also inherited from `MainViewController` and when I add `#import "MyProjectName-Swift.h"` to `MainViewController.h`, all swift classes got confused.

I hope you understand my question. The scenario is a bit complicated and sorry if I haven't explained it any better.

Also, is there a way to import only a single swift class in objective-c instead of doing this `#import "MyProjectName-Swift.h"`?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only import "ProductName-Swift.h" in .m files.

> To avoid cyclical references, don’t import Swift into an Objective-C header file. Instead, you can forward declare a Swift class to use it in an Objective-C header. Note that you cannot subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.

There is no way to import single Swift class to ObjC file. `ProductName-Swift.h` is an autogenerated header that defines Objective-C interfaces for all Swift classes in your project that are either annotated with `@objc` or inherit from `NSObject`.